# "Born + a name"

Tags: phrase-meaning

In

> **Born Lev Bronshtein** on 7 November 1879 in the village of Yanovka in the Ukraine, [Leon Trotsky](http://www.historyinanhour.com/2012/08/21/leon-trotsky-summary/), the son of a prosperous Jewish farmer, became involved in politics from a young age.

Does *Born Lev Bronshtein* mean that Lev Bronshtein was Leon Trotsky's mother?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. *Born Lev Bronshtein* means that when Leon Trotsky was born, his name was Lev Bronshtein.

*Born **to** Lev Bronshtein* would mean that Lev Bronshtein was his parent (mother or father).

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of "Born Lev Bronshtein"  is Born **as** Lev Bronshtein.

That was his original name. "Leon Trotsky" was an adopted name.